# Reference ActiveRecord attributes in textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple invoice application, and I would like to allow the users to customize the text on the invoice. In addition to this, they should be able to reference specific attributes in my models, i.e. "This is a test {{Model.attribute}}", and once the text is parsed the tag is replaced with the value of that attribute.

I have looked a bit at redcloth, textile and handlebars, but it does look like a little bit overkill to be honest. For instance I would not like to allow the users to input any HTML.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. There is probably a gem for this that I just havent found yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're probably looking for a front-end framework like `angularjs`

Comment: @mihai Why??? Do you understand the question? This has nothing to do with front-end frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [liquid](http://rubygems.org/gems/liquid) with [simpleformat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) which will sanitise the text.

Comment: Arhh, liquid - I am surprised I did not find that one on my own. Thanks.